# Android - 2 Timer or something else?

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I want to program a little Tamagotchi for practice.
And I'm just thinking how I should do with the values​​, hunger and sleep.
Should I run two timers that change every 10 minutes the values​​, and then save it or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Probably access the devices internal clock and do actions based on that rather than using timers.

Comment: How exactly do you mean?
I want that every 15 minutes the values ​​are changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the Tamagotchi to be hungry or sleepy while the app is running, use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html). These are Android specific Timers.

If you want the Tamagotchi to change states while the app isn't running, you need to create a repeating alarm with the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to start the app.

Comment: Hm, i want both. But i think, i can use the system time when i start the app, to correct the stats.

Comment: "i want both" You can continue to use the AlarmManager while the app is running. It is simply overkill to code an AlarmManager to only run while the app is active. "i think, i can use the system time when i start the app, to correct the stats." If you don't want to (obnoxiously) interrupt the user every 10-15 minutes at night, this is a good choice too. You can use it to inform the user that their neglected Tamagotchi has _silently_ passed away if they haven't fed it in a week.

Comment: I will look at the handler and the Runnable. Hope I find good tutorials on this. Thanks.